# Get IHostingEnvironment in integration test

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am trying to write a integration test for the following class but I am stuck with getting the IHostingEnvironment in my test. I am assuming that I should be able to get IHostingEnvironment from the TestServer but no dice. Am I missing something basic? Is this a scenario more appropriate for unit test than integration test?

**Actual Class**

```
public class PasswordResetMessage : IMessage
    {
        private readonly PasswordReset passwordReset;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment iHostingEnvironment;
        public PasswordResetMessage(IHostingEnvironment iHostingEnvironment, PasswordReset passwordReset)
        {
            this.passwordReset = passwordReset;
            this.iHostingEnvironment=iHostingEnvironment;
        }
        public string Get()
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var pathToFile = Path.Combine(iHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "EmailTemplates", "password_reset.txt");
            using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            return stringBuilder.Replace("{{ActionURL}}", passwordReset.ActionURL).ToString();
        }
    }
```

**Integration Test:**

```
public class PasswordResetMessageTest
    {
        private PasswordResetMessage passwordResetMessage;
        private readonly TestServer testServer;
        public PasswordResetMessageTest()
        {
            testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
            passwordResetMessage = new PasswordResetMessage(**<IDon'tKnowWhatToPassHere>**, new PasswordReset());
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Get()
        {
            var message=passwordResetMessage.Get();
            Assert.Contains(message, "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could/should use a mock. See the Moq package for instance.

Comment: Code under test is tightly coupled to implementation concerns (ie `IO.File`), making it difficult to unit test in isolation, which is what this 
[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is trying to perform an integration test to try to get around that issue.